# Criterion for completely splitting primes in a radical extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

Given $d \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $a \in \mathbb{Q}^*$, let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d, a^{1/d})$, where $\zeta_d$ is a primitive $d$th root of unity.

I'm trying to prove that: "A prime number $p$ splits completely in $K$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod d$ and $a$ is a $d$th power modulo $p$"

I tried to use Dedekind-Kummer factorization theorem (the one that relates the decomposition of a prime $p$ with the factorization of a polynomial modulo $p$) but the reasoning seems quite complicate. I guess that there's a more clever method.

Thank for any help

**Notes:** (1) It might be necessary to exclude finitely many primes from the statement of the criterion, like the one dividing the numerator or denominator of $a$; (2) Since $a$ is a rational number, by $d$th power modulo $p$ I mean that there exists $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that the numerator of $a - b^d$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: $p$ splits completely in $K$ if and only if it splits completely in $\mathbb Q(a^{1/d})$. Indeed, if it splits in $\mathbb Q(a^{1/d})$ then it also splits in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_d a^{1/d})$ (as the two fields are isomorphic) and $K$ is the compositum of both fields. $\mathbb Q(a^{1/d})$ is more amenable to the Kummer-Dedekind theorem.

Comment: @Mathmo123 In general, $\mathbb{Q}(a^{1/d})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d a^{1/d})$ are not isomorphic. A counterexample is given by $a = 8$ and $d = 3$.

Comment: Of course you're right. I'm implicitly assuming that $\mathbb Q(a^{1/d})$ has degree $d$ over $\mathbb Q$, in which case my argument is correct. In any case, you can use the Kummer-Dedekind theorem to prove that $p$ splits completely in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_d)$ if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod d$ and that $p$ splits in $\mathbb Q(a^{1/d})$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod d$ and $a$ is a $d$-th power mod $p$ (the latter condition is necessary, but the first may not be, such as in your example)

Comment: @Mathmo123 I agree with what you say about $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d)$, but I don't understand the part on $\mathbb{Q}(a^{1/d})$. To apply the Dedekind-Kummer theorem to $\mathbb{Q}(a^{1/d})$ I need that $a$ is an algebraic integer, but in my case it may not. (The Dedekind-Kummer theorem I know is from pag. 47-48 of Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory). Also, it's not clear to me what the conductor is.

Comment: You can always scale up $a^{1/d}$ by a rational to assume that it is an algebraic integer (as $\mathbb Q((a/b)^{1/d}) = \mathbb Q((ab^{d-1})^{1/d})$. You're right about the second condition. It will only cause issues if $p\mid d$ or $p\mid a$ (the discriminant of $x^d-a$ up to sign is $d^da^{d-1})$. The first case cannot occur by assumption. In the second case, $p$ will typically be ramified in $\mathbb Q(a^{1/d})$.